# Hide / collapse / visible dockpanel in sidebar on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am working on sidebar wpf application. Sidebar has several dockpanels. My question is, how can collapse / visible same of dockpanels in sidebar based on click buttons. For example: Button 1 should be collapse dockPanel1 and everything inside in. Button 2 should be display it.

Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="370*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" x:Name="sidebarControl">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Top" Source="{StaticResource logo}" />
                <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="160" Name="dockPanel1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label Content="Label1"></Label>
                            <Label Content="Label2"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label Content="Label3"></Label>
                            <Label Content="Label4"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="160" Name="dockPanel2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                            <!-- other content -->
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <!-- other content -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using BooleanToVisibilityConverter. In ViewModel i put boolean property named IsVisible. Wherever i change my IsVisible property (set to true or false) BooleanToVisibilityConverter class check it and change dockpanel visibility. Here is my code:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="160" Name="dockPanel1" 
                           Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                   <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label Content="Label1"></Label>
                            <Label Content="Label2"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label Content="Label3"></Label>
                            <Label Content="Label4"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```